# How would you build report to be sent to multiple users?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssis

I need to create a report (table like report) for 50+ users. 
Each one with the data for particular user has to be created and sent by e-mail.

How would you create and automate that process?

Is it possible to involve the following programs to do that task?

```
-Sql reporting services
-Integration services
-Other techniques?
```

Thanks

Comment: I really don't understand your question, and also not sure what "raport" means? It all seems very vague... Any way at all you can clarify and be more specific?

Comment: It was just a typographic error. Really, You didn't realize that it was about "report". What else seems vague for you?

Comment: Sarcasm isn't helpful, but your edits to your question were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) and with tools such as Report Builder or Business Intelligence Development Studio create your report which has input parameter UserId (and maybe few additional parameters). Then in your SQL you should write query and based on that query in SSRS generate your report. 
Then you can use ReportViewer control for creating a client (if you don't want to use standart report server client). This control available for Web and also for WinForms. 
For beginning you can read this tutorial: [SSRS Tutorial](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssrs_2008_tutorial.htm)

For automation you can use ReportExecutionService and method Render to get export file of your report in code behind - [MSDN Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsexecutionservice2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

And then send this file via email.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. How would you then automate sending part? I thought rather about something like generating a report and send it using iterations in SSIS. I am more interested in sending techniques for such tasks. Is there such function built in SSRS or should i create my own windows service to perform sending operations?

Comment: You can do this with SSRS. For first you need to configure report server for mail delivery: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345234(v=sql.105).aspx , then in your report manager (http://[servername]/Reports") you should subscribe for your report: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157386(v=sql.105).aspx .But for subscribing use IE browser. Others don't support this.